# How to correctly count the probability for a computer game situation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Imagine we have the following situation in a computer game:

One player has two minions with 30 and 6 hitpoints correspondingly. Another player casts a spell which does 12 times 1 damage (for each of 12 iterations the target is chosen randomly from available enemies). If a minion’s health became 0 it dies so it won’t more be targeted.

The question is, **what’s the probability that the 6 health minion will be killed during execution of the spell and how do I count it?**

I assume that I should use combinatorics here to initially understand what’s the probability that it won’t be killed and then substract it from 1, but I don’t know how exactly I’m supposed to count this.

Any useful links will be highly appreciated (I would like to learn more in this area).

Comment: The spell does 12 damage, enough to kill the minion with 6hp, and it picks a random target. There are two targets. The probability is $1/2$.

Comment: @MikePierce Given the context, I would assume that each of the twelve points of damage will have a target randomly selected.  It sounds like he is asking a question about a C'Thun deck from Hearthstone.

Comment: @MikePierce Excuse me for the unclearness. I modified the question to be more precise. The target is chosen randomly for each of 12 iterations of the spell.

Comment: @JMoravitz You've got me right, that's exactly what the question is about! :)

Comment: @IvanYurchenko Now...if you ask how to explicitly calculate the results of playing a C'Thun against a Grim Patron... I would just run simulations.  I can't think of any convenient method except markov chains, but the massive number of states makes that horribly unfeasible.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hah I didn’t even think about this! I think if the number of operations isn’t big (like 12 shots and 1 Grim Patron) it can easily be solved by a program that will just simulate all cases and count number of these which correspond to some condition. But if the numbers are like billions I guess even Watson would have a hard time to calculate that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us temporarily **ignore** the mechanic that a dead creature cannot be targeted.

Relate this problem to the question of "If I flip twelve fair coins, what is the probability that I get more heads than tails?"  (heads corresponding to hitting the 30 health minion, tails corresponding to hitting the 6 health minion)

We could approach directly using the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which says that with $n$ trials and probability of success $p$ for each trial, the probability of having exactly $k$ successes total will be

$$Pr(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

So, by setting $n=12, p=0.5$ we could calculate $P(X=7)+P(X=8)+P(X=9)+\dots+P(X=12)$, and this would work, however it is very tedious.

Instead, to make things easier, notice that it is equally likely that there are more heads than tails than vice versa.  We ask then what is the probability of a tie.

This would correspond to having six heads and six tails, which occurs with probability $Pr(X=6)=\binom{12}{6}\cdot (0.5)^6\cdot (0.5)^6 = \frac{231}{1024}\approx 0.2256$

We know that $1=Pr(\text{more heads})+Pr(\text{tie})+Pr(\text{more tails}) = 2Pr(\text{more heads})+\frac{231}{1024}$

Completing the necessary arithmetic then, we find $Pr(\text{more heads})=\frac{793}{2048}\approx 0.387$

Thus, the probability that the minion with 30 health took seven or more points of the damage, or worded another way, the minion with 6 health survives is $\approx 0.387$

---

As an aside, extending the problem to allow more minions on the field, look instead to the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine two urns and 12 balls. After you distribute the balls randomly between the urns you take all but 6 from the second urn and move them to the first one (or move none if the second urn has 6 or less balls in it). Your question is if the second urn 5 or less balls in it (then the minion would be still alive).

However, moving the balls does not change anything with respect to the above question, so it's enough to calculate if the second urn got at most 5 balls in it without moving anything.

Direct calculation shows:
[$$\sum_{i=0}^{5}\binom{12}{i}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{12} = \frac{793}{2048} \approx 0.3872$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B12,k%5D*2%5E(-12),%7Bk,0,5%7D%5D)

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$